# Product Image does not show on magento backend while upload

Tags: magento-2.1

I try to upload product  image in magento backend but it does not upload  and not show in backend and frontend i try to php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy  but not work can any one tell me how solve

Comment: Verify that you give proper permission to media folder. And also check consol or log file is that any error generate while you try to upload image.

Comment: Are you getting a blank image in the backend or just no image?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the language files.

I followed the next steps:

Set Configuration -> General -> Locale Options -> Locale

For Default Config: admin language (English) US
Also, check if your admin language is set to en_US.

I did now:
Delete /pub/static/_requirejs
Delete /pub/static/adminhtml
Delete /pub/static/frontend

SSH
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean